# problem with double scripting, because of speed reasons, awk verse bash builtin

Tags: bash, awk

I have a lot of bash functions, which contain a bash builtin code and the same code rewritten in awk code. I want to get rid off this.
I use the bash builtin for short strings, and awk for long strings, so a lot of my
functions have a boolean for length type. (0) for short strings (bash builtin), (1) for long strings (awk).

For short strings bash builtin is faster.

I want to give an example:
the g_SO_formatText_width function, which formats a text according to overhanded columns width by break words or try to keep words unbroken, depending on boolean.
In the text there also could be font tags like <b:u:color 255;123:120> , which is filtered out and not relevant for the data text and calculations on it , where to break words. the font tags are converted to ANSI escape codes by a other function.
this function only formats the text

#!/bin/bash

```
            declare g_RV="" g_ESC=$'\x1b'; declare -i g_tabSpaces="8"

            #-- call:        g_SO_formatText_width [text STR] [max columns INT] [length type bINT] [word wrap bINT] [text type bINT]
            #-- description: formats the text appearance, so that the text appears with a max columns width, either with breaking words or trying to keep words unbroken
            #--              word splitting is used! use set -o noglob to prohibit that data characters * ? [] are recognized as file patterns, or even more characters, if extented glob is on.
            #-- parameters:  $1 ... text STR - text to format
            #--              $2 ... max columns INT - max columns should be lower than terminal columns, to see an effect
            #--              $3 ... length type bINT optional - faster for short strings (0), faster for long strings with awk (1) - Standard:0
            #--              $4 ... word wrap bINT optional - try to keep word unbroken (0), break word (1), Standard:0
            #--              $5 ... text type bINT optional - normal text (0), FSS Font Style Simple text (1)
            #-- returnValue: written to g_RV - STR .. the formatted text
            #-- depends on:  variables - g_RV, g_ESC, g_tabSpaces;
            function g_SO_formatText_width ()
                {
                if [[ $2 -eq 0 ]];then return 1; fi
                #-- bash builtins
                if [[ $3 -eq 0 ]]; then
                    local -a dataText_ARR=() formatText_ARR=()
                    #-- text     ... complete text overhanded - which can contain format strings (text)
                    #-- dataText ... the data of the text without format strings
                    #-- iline    ... input line - a line of dataText separated with \n
                    #-- oline    ... output line - a calculated line of text on screen according to columns limit and respecting \n in source text
                    local text dataText iline oline output=""

                    #-- iline_SIndex ... input line startIndex, for reading characters
                    #-- iline_l oline_l  ... iline oline length
                    #-- oline_dl ... length difference, between two different oline lengths (oline is shortened to last space)
                    local -i i oline_aChars=$2 iline_SIndex iline_l oline_l oline_dl

                    #-- \t becomes \n\t - so tabulator appears only at first place of a new line, making calculation of tab action easier
                    text=${1//$'\t'/$'\n\t'}

                    #-- FSS text
                    if [[ $5 -eq 1 ]]; then
                        local textPart savIFS=$IFS
                        dataText_ARR[0]=${text%%"$g_ESC"*}

                        IFS=$g_ESC; i=0; for textPart in ${text:${#dataText_ARR[0]}+1}
                            do
                            formatText_ARR[i]=${textPart%%>*}">"
                            dataText_ARR[i+1]=${textPart:${#formatText_ARR[i]}}
                            ((i++))
                            done
                        IFS=$savIFS

                    #-- normal text
                    else dataText_ARR[0]=$text; formatText_ARR[0]=""
                    fi

                    for i in ${!dataText_ARR[*]}
                        do
                        dataText=${dataText_ARR[$i]}

                        while true
                            do
                            #-- search for first input line
                            iline=${dataText%%$'\n'*}
                            iline_l=${#iline}

                            #-- subtract line characters from columns limit, if <0 line too big!
                            ((oline_aChars-=iline_l, iline_SIndex=0))

                            #-- if input line too big, then split it to output lines with allowed columns amount separated by \n,
                            #-- loop breaks, when the rest of the input line is small enough to suit in one output line, that's the case, when oLine_aChars>=0
                            #-- case: try to keep word unbroken
                            if [[ $4 -eq 0 ]]; then
                                while ((oline_aChars<0))
                                    do
                                    oline=${iline:iline_SIndex:oline_aChars}
                                    if [[ ${iline:oline_aChars-1:2} == [^$' ,;'][^$' '] ]]; then
                                        oline_l=${#oline}; oline=${oline% *}; ((oline_dl= ${#oline}-oline_l))
                                        if ((oline_dl<0)); then oline+=" "; fi
                                        ((oline_aChars+=oline_dl+1))
                                    fi
                                    output+=$oline$'\n'
                                    ((iline_SIndex=oline_aChars,oline_aChars+=$2))
                                    done
                            #-- case: break word
                            else
                                while ((oline_aChars<0))
                                    do
                                    oline=${iline:iline_SIndex:oline_aChars}
                                    output+=$oline$'\n'
                                    ((iline_SIndex=oline_aChars,oline_aChars+=$2))
                                    done
                            fi
                            #-- if iline is (now) not too big, simply add it to output
                            output+=${iline:iline_SIndex}

                            #-- check if next line exists
                            if (($iline_l<${#dataText})); then
                                #--shorten dataText by cutting out the acutal input line
                                dataText=${dataText:$iline_l+1};
                                #-- Tabulator sign recognition - check if first character of a theoretical new line is tab sign
                                #-- if so prohibit new line!
                                if [[ ${dataText:0:1} == $'\t' ]]; then
                                    #-- calculate the amount of spaces the tab sign causes according to its position in the line
                                    #-- with oline_aChars and max columns $2 get the actual position - with g_tabSpaces, calculate the amount of spaces
                                    ((oline_aChars-=g_tabSpaces-1-($2-oline_aChars)%g_tabSpaces));
                                    #-- if oline gets below zero, when subtracting the amount of spaces, tab would cause
                                    #-- then it moves to beginning of new line, so add \n reset oline_aChars to max columns
                                    if ((oline_aChars<0)); then
                                        dataText=${dataText:1}
                                        output+=$'\n'; oline_aChars=$2
                                    fi
                                #-- close iline with \n and reset oline_aChars for new line
                                else output+=$'\n'; oline_aChars=$2; fi
                                if ((${#dataText}==0)); then break; fi
                            else break; fi
                            done

                        output+=${formatText_ARR[$i]};
                        done
                    g_RV="$output"
                #-- awk
                else
                    #-- awk script begin
                    g_RV=$(awk \
            '   BEGIN {textType='"$5"'; wordWrap='"$4"'; tabSpaces='"$g_tabSpaces"'; maxColumns='"$2"'; if (textType) RS="'"$g_ESC"'"; else RS="\x00"; oline_aChars=maxColumns; i=0 }
                {gsub(/\t/,"\n\t"); if (i) {indexGT=index($0,">"); dataText_ARR[i]=substr($0,indexGT+1); formatText_ARR[i-1]=substr($0,1,indexGT);} else dataText_ARR[0]=$0 ;i++ }
                END {
                    for (i in dataText_ARR) {
                        dataText=dataText_ARR[i];
                        while (1) {
                            indexNL=index(dataText,"\n"); if (!indexNL) indexNL=length(dataText)+1;
                            iline=substr(dataText,1,indexNL-1); iline_l=length(iline);
                            oline_aChars-=iline_l; iline_SIndex=1;
                            oline_l=iline_l+oline_aChars;

                            if (wordWrap) {
                                while (oline_aChars<0)  {
                                    oline=substr(iline,iline_SIndex,oline_l); printf "%s",oline "\n";
                                    iline_SIndex+=oline_l; oline_l=maxColumns; oline_aChars+=maxColumns;}}
                            else {
                                while (oline_aChars<0) {
                                    oline=substr(iline,iline_SIndex,oline_l);
                                    if (match(substr(iline,iline_SIndex+oline_l-1,2),/[^ ,;][^ ]/)) {
                                        if (match(oline,/.* /)) oline=substr(oline,1,RLENGTH);
                                        oline_aChars+=RLENGTH-oline_l; oline_l=RLENGTH; }
                                    printf "%s" , oline "\n";
                                    iline_SIndex+=oline_l; oline_l=maxColumns; oline_aChars+=maxColumns}}

                            printf "%s",substr(iline,iline_SIndex);
                            if (iline_l<length(dataText)) {
                                dataText=substr(dataText,iline_l+2);
                                if (substr(dataText,1,1) == "\t") {
                                    oline_aChars-=tabSpaces-1-(maxColumns-oline_aChars)%tabSpaces;\
                                    if ((oline_aChars<0)) {
                                        dataText=substr(dataText,2);
                                        printf "%s","\n"; oline_aChars=maxColumns; }}
                                else {printf "%s","\n"; oline_aChars=maxColumns; }
                                if (length(dataText)==0) break; }
                            else break; }
                        printf "%s",formatText_ARR[i]; }}' <<< $1;)
                    #-- awk script end
                    fi
                }
```

you see nearly the same code, doubled in one function.
here a test function, which can be added to the code above

```
            #-- $1 amount of 'Hello World ' in text, $2 columns where to break word
            function helloWorld_test
                {
                for ((i=0;i<$1; i++)); do text+="Hello World "; done

                #g_SO_formatText_width [text STR] [max columns INT] [length type bINT] [word wrap bINT] [text type bINT]
                echo -e "\nbash builtin: $1"
                time g_SO_formatText_width "$text" $2 0 0 0
                echo -e "\nawk script: $1"
                time g_SO_formatText_width "$text" $2 1 0 0
                echo -e "\n$g_RV";
                }

            helloWorld_test 10 70
            helloWorld_test 50 70
            helloWorld_test 80 70
            helloWorld_test 100 70
            helloWorld_test 1000 70
```

for formatting 50 "Hello World"'s i get

bash builtin: 50

real    0m0,001s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,001s

awk script: 50

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,001s
sys 0m0,002s

for formatting 80 "hello world "s i get
bash builtin: 80

real    0m0,002s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,002s

awk script: 80

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,003s
sys 0m0,000s

so let's say 3ms difference on short text, that#s not much but doing a lot of conversion, the difference would grow.

I'm a Linux beginner,
I think the file awk has over 700kb, and every time i call the command in bash it will be loaded to memory and then the script has to be read in and evaluted.
I think the problem is the loading, is that right.
is there a command, with which i could keep awk in memory over the time and only overhand the script to it, or how could i increase the speed of awk, to get rid off this bash builtins code.
I'm still wondering, why bash is so slow on text manipulations. There are no typed variables like boolean, double float, int32 and so on. its all about strings.

Comment: @markp-fuso i'm writing library functions for myself, the function above is also a library function. for example - writing a shell script for express vpn, setting the vpn server, put a rectangle on screen, where answer text is written in, for example, a list of all vpn servers and around the rectangle put some mouse buttons, connect vpn, disconnect, and so on, to write in the text in the rectangle, i use g_SO_formatText_width, to limit that characters exceed the rectangle.   The problem with library functions is, you don't know where they are used in future.

Comment: the question was, how can i invoke the awk command faster - but you said "the big time savings are going to come from reducing the number of OS processes you have to spawn" - in a script often OS processes are started, so i thought there would be a possibility to invoke a often used command in script, like awk faster.

Comment: comments: use `${#1}` (or `${#var}`) to get arg/var char length automatically, or `wc` for files. Look at `par` and `fmt` for soft wrapping, `fold` for hard wrapping.

Comment: @Dan thanx, i know fmt and fold, but i can't use them because, the text i have to format to a certain width, can contain font style tags like <b:u>hello</b:u> world. that means hello is bold and underlined. fmt will recognize the characters as text and not as style format, if i convert this font style tags to ansi escape codes i have the same problem. a='hello world hello world hello world hello world'; echo $a | fmt -w 32;   in comparison to a='hello world'$'\e[''38;2;122;34;85m hello world hello world hello world';  echo $a | fmt -w 32; .  That's why i wrote my own function with awk....

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza Sure. Just suggestions that may help. I meant to also  mention the tools `ansi2html` and `ansi2text`, part of the `colorized-logs` package on debian, https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs. Also some shell implementations here: https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/tree/master/scripts. These may be relevant.

Comment: If your intended question is just something like "when I have an external command I need to call repeatedly from a bash script, is there anything I can do to have it start faster" then there's a LOT of irrelevant complexity in your question that's throwing people off and causing them to try to help you with your script rather than solve that problem. You also might be better off asking that question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash or even better on usenet at comp.unix.shell.

Comment: @Ed Morton and Dan thx, i will take a look at ansi2html ansi2text, and try the unix stackexchange forum. The thing about, why i post the bash function in here is to show that i had to double code, only because of 3ms, and i dont want to write an extra code for bash builtin and an extra code for awk, instead push awk to start  as fast that it cuts off the speed advantage on short strings with bash builtin.. thanx